# Going to next page and scraping links in nightmareJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, nightmare

I am trying to goto next page and scrape links until the last available page using `nightmareJS`. Although I am having Issues and didn't had any luck on how to get it to work.

**CODE**

```
const Nightmare = require('nightmare');
const nightmare = Nightmare({ show: true, executionTimeout: 3000})
const imageUrl = [];


function getImages() {
  const images = document.querySelectorAll('.item a img');
  const img = [];
  for(let i = 0; i<images.length; i++) {
      img.push(images[i].src);
  }
  return img;
}


nightmare
    .goto('https://hidurl/images/search/dogs/')
    .scrollTo(20368, 0)
    .wait(1000)
    .evaluate(getImages)
    .then(a => {
      const aFiltered = a.filter(word => word.includes('.jpg'));
      for(let i = 0; i<aFiltered.length; i++) {
        imageUrl.push(aFiltered[i]);
        }
      console.log(imageUrl);     
         return nightmare
                .click('#content > div > a')
                .scrollTo(20368, 0)
                .wait(1000)
                .evaluate(getImages)
                .then( a => {

                    const aFiltered = a.filter(word => word.includes('.jpg'));
                    for(let i = 0; i<aFiltered.length; i++) {
                      imageUrl.push(aFiltered[i]);
                      }
                    console.log(imageUrl);


            })    
})
.catch(error => {
    console.error(error)
})
```

I want to get an array with all the links available on the page. I am only able to go to maximum two pages as of now, without repeating code. I am getting started with NightMare and was hoping to find some help on how to go over multiple pages and populating array as I move.

Comment: Where did you attach the click function? What error did it give you?

Comment: After evaluate it gave error from catch claw.. I also added wait to see if it clicks but it doesn't.

Comment: What error exactly? can you change the code to `.catch(console.error)` and share the error?

Comment: @Md.AbuTaher  I have updated the question and code, It works just not sure how to repeat the processes, of going till the last page.

Answer (score 0):

Alright Fixed Issue using Generator function and control flow node library [vo](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vo)

```
const Nightmare = require('nightmare');
const vo = require('vo');
const nightmare = Nightmare({ show: true, executionTimeout: 3000 });
const imageUrl = [];


function getImages() {
    const images = document.querySelectorAll('.item a img');
    const img = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
        img.push(images[i].src);
    }
    return img;
}


vo(run)(function(err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
});


function* run() {
    let MAX_PAGE = 5,
        currentPage = 0,
        nextExists = true;


    yield nightmare
        .goto('https://someurl/images/search/dogs/')
        .scrollTo(20368, 0)
        .wait(1000);

    nextExists = yield nightmare.exists('#content > div > a');

    while (nextExists && currentPage < MAX_PAGE) {
        yield nightmare
            .scrollTo(20368, 0)
            .wait(1000)
            .evaluate(getImages)
            .then(a => {
                const aFiltered = a.filter(word => word.includes('.jpg'));
                for (let i = 0; i < aFiltered.length; i++) {
                    imageUrl.push(aFiltered[i]);
                }
            });

        yield nightmare
                    .click('#content > div > a')
                    .wait('body')
                    .wait(1000);

        currentPage++;
        nextExists = yield nightmare.exists('#content > div > a');
    }

    console.table(imageUrl);
    yield nightmare.end();
}
```

Can go to many pages on any site with pagination using NightMareJS now.